# How do I disable Instagram notifications?

Tags: notifications, push-notifications, instagram

How do I disable push notifications for Instagram? As much as possible, I don't want apps to do any push notifications (except for MMS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite easy.

1. Go to Instagram app
2. Tap on your own name in stream (or the card icon) to go to your profile
3. Tap the 3 vertical dots next to your name
4. Tap `Edit profile`
5. Scroll down, tap `Push notifications`
6. Uncheck what you don't want. Voila!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, Instagram still pushes notifications when your facebook friends join Instagram, even if you have disabled all notifications in the Instagram app.  To try and actually disable all Instagram notifications, I went to my phone's "Settings", selected "Apps" (under the "Device" category), looked at all downloaded apps, selected "Instagram", and unchecked the "Show notifications" option.  It warned me that I might miss important updates (thank goodness) and I said "ok".

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for Android Samsung S4 (similar but slightly different from what Ponder wrote):

- Select "Settings"
- then "More"
- then select "Application Manager"
- Scroll to find the Instagram App and select it.
- Then, uncheck the box that reads "Show Notifications."

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch your Instagram app from the app drawer.
2. As the app opens up, click on the button for Direct Message, which is often located at the top right corner.
3. Tap on it and all your direct message conversations you have ever had on Instagram would appear.
4. Now click on any conversation that you would like to mute.
5. After you open that very conversation, tap on the ‘i’ button that appears on the top right corner again.
6. After you click on it, a new screen would appear and it would let you mute that very conversation and in future you wouldn’t have any alerts or notifications from that conversation on Instagram direct messaging.

If you still feel difficult to follow , here is the  clear picture demonstration of the above process in the following link                                   [how to mute notifications of instagram notification](http://thegeekdaily.com/how-to-mute-notification-of-particular-instagram-conversation/)

Comment: OP wants to disable all the notifications from Instagram app.Your post answers to disable a particular conversation. This does not cover  other notifications from instagram such as when someone likes/comments on your photo or someone follows you.